# Issues w vagrant ssh: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

Tags: vagrant

first off I'm very new to programming and web development. I'm currently working through a Udacity course on SQL.

I'm trying to install VM and Vagrant and have run into this issue. Vagrant installed fine, and I'm able to run vagrant up, but when I run **vagrant ssh** I'm getting this message:

.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

I'll attach a screen here.

I'm on a Mac. Big Sur 11.5.2

Vagrant version 2.2.18

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance![enter image description here][1]

bash-3.2$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04-i386' version '2.3.5' is up to date...
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
bash-3.2$ vagrant ssh
/Users/scott27/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
bash-3.2$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider moving your config file to a backup and trying again.

```
mv /Users/scott27/.ssh/config /Users/scott27/.ssh/config.bak
```

Then try `vagrant up` again and if it works then the issue is in your config file, troubleshoot that separately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the existing ssh config file it is better to instead let vagrant point to its own config file using the `config.ssh.config` in `vagrantfile`

I am on Windows but I assume it is similar on mac. I updated my Vagrantfile like so:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.ssh.config = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/ssh_config')
```

As you can see I point to a ssh_config file that I created, since an empty string resulted in an error.